# Website not viewable from BlackBerries

Tags: blackberry

We are having some annoying issues with BlackBerry phones. For some odd reason, our webpages aren't downloaded fully by **some** BB phones and I don't have clue what it could be.

If you have a BB, please try [www.safarinow.com](http://www.safarinow.com).

We are currently mainly experiencing this issue on the BB Curve 8520, but we don't have a lot of BB's around here to properly test. I have used the BB simulator for this BB and also for different models, but of course, on the simulators everything works fine. In order to browse the Internet on the BB simulator, it requires you to have the MDS service installed and I assume this works differently than the live server.

Something strange is that when you change the character encoding (BlackBerry browser menu -> Set encoding), it usually does load the full page...

Any clues? Please help :-)

Some articles I read

- http://www.builtfromsource.com/2008/08/27/major-bug-with-blackberry-browser-and-multiple-cookies/
  -> This doesn't seem to be the issue
- http://www.blackberryforums.com.au/forums/general-bes-discussion/284-request-entity-too-large.html -> We are not getting an error, although page request size might be an issue

Comment: The site works fine on BB 9360

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with the HTML, or could it be the network disconnecting while loading this large page? Have you tried it on both wifi and cellular networks?

Comment: Nope, not sure. But it's quite difficult to test, it's a large site that runs with deployment cycles and it isn't easy to do 'quick' fixes.. We're definitely trying to reduce the size of the site though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a lot of BlackBerries have Javascript turned off. And even if it's turned on, there is a checkbox for "Terminate slow running scripts" (something like that). We use jQuery Mobile, which is pretty heavy, so that was causing the issues. Ticking both checkboxes solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should add an Encoding tag on your page's header.

Something like `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to add this, but the headers are sent correctly, try: http://web-sniffer.net/

Answer (score 1):

This could be an issue specifically related to the browser rending engine.  It's a long shot but make sure your HTML validates.  The browser on certain Blackberries may be choking on improperly validated HTML.

Validate markup for your site: [The W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.safarinow.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

The service found 41 errors and 9 warnings.  It's worth eliminating as many errors as possible and re-testing.

Comment: Yes, the invalid HTML is definitely an issue that needs to be solved either way. I'll give it a try, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alison has some very good advice.

One other thing to look into is the amount of, and specifics of, javascript on the page. Before OS 6 and the Web Kit based browser, support for javascript on BlackBerry devices was intentionally limited.

Comment: Ideally we should put all the JavaScript at the bottom of the page, which will improve load speed as well. However, if you turn of JavaScript, you can see that the page loads 'fine', everything is there, the JS doesn't work.